# Gift tax implication If one would pay large and voluntary child support to girlfriend (have common child)?

Tags: united-states, gift-tax, children, marriage

If I understand correctly, if one transfers more than $17,000 to his girlfriend (not married) with whom he has a child then that would need to be reported on his gift tax return; And would consume his lifetime gift tax exemption.

However, what If he pays large child support to her? My understanding is that it would not need to be reported as gift, but:

1. Do they need court order or can child support be voluntary?
2. Are there limits how large such child support can be?
3. Do they have to live separate?
4. Does she have to use all of that money for child needs or can keep for herself too?
5. Does it matter who claims child as dependent on their tax returns?

Comment: You need a lawyer. Very dangerous trusting the internet for advice on issues like this with major implications if you get it wrong.

Comment: @JohnFx Already did. Marriage Lawyer (with whom discussed prenup) told to talk to Accountant; and Accountant told to talk to lawyer. Is there a special qualified lawyer (or accountant) one should look for?

Comment: @user389238: See littleadv's answer. A lawyer specializing in family law sounds like the right place to start.

Comment: Which jurisdiction are you in? Lots of countries use $ for currency and the answer to this could vary massively depending on where you are.

Answer (score 6):

> Do they need court order or can child support be voluntary?

Yes, you need a court order. Voluntary child support is called "gift". From tax perspective unless there's a legal requirement to pay - you're giving a gift.

You can gift money to your child, instead of the girlfriend (since that's your intention anyway), and then your girlfriend will be *obligated* to spend it to the benefit of the child or keep it in a UMTA account.

The reason to talk to the lawyer is because you can create a situation where by starting giving gifts you can no longer stop. While on one hand you'll get that order that would allow you avoiding the gift tax problem, on the other hand you'll lose the control you currently have over your finances.

One alternative would be to give money to a trust to the benefit of the child, instead of giving money to your girlfriend and calling it "voluntary child support". But IANAL, you should discuss this with a local family law specialist attorney.

Comment: Is this a US-specific answer? The OP hasn't specified (yet) where they are so you should probably make that clear in case they're not in the US.

Comment: @Vicky the $17K exemption is part of the US gift tax code. Also, people who think that they live in the only country in the world tend to be from the US.

Comment: @littleadv if this was money.stackexchange.co.uk, then there's a much higher chance that OP would tag his question `united-states`.

Comment: @RonJohn as opposed to money.stackexchange.co.us that it is now?

Comment: @littleadv you certainly know that `.com` is by default a US-based TLD, just like `.edu` and `.org`.

Comment: @RonJohn no, that's not true, and thank you for demonstrating the point. Only .gov and .mil TLDs are owned by the US government.

Comment: @littleadv c'mon, man.  You know that "by default a US-based TLD" doesn't mean "owned by the US government".

Comment: @RonJohn what does it mean? Whose default is that? You do realize that you're exemplifying that exact arrogance that I was referring to, don't you? The ".us" TLD does exist.

Comment: @littleadv you're confusing arrogance with naming rights: the people who create something get to name it.  Americans created .com, .edu, .org, etc for the purpose of communicating with other Americans.

Comment: @littleadv next you'll be angry that ASCII stands for the American Standard Code for Information Interchange.

Comment: @RonJohn not angry, but the US-centric standardization did cause significant problems. At some point, thankfully, the IT industry switched from ASCII to UTF. Having some experience programming and using computers in the early 1990's I remember the pain caused by ASCII very vividly. And yes, it is arrogance. Naming things for your own personal convenience disregarding literally the rest of the world is... arrogant.

Comment: @littleadv when you create something *new*, you name it for yourself, not for hypothetical people 30 years later, half way across the globe. Or do you think it was Muslim arrogance that Muslims gave Arabic names to the stars they discovered?

Comment: @RonJohn generally when you create a standard you make it useful for everyone, or it fails. ASCII is a great example of such a failure. Your insisting that Americans *now* are motivated by anything but ignorance or arrogance when they assume that everyone else on the internet lives in the same town as them and feel no need to specify the locality/jurisdiction (even within their very federalized country) is an example of that exact ignorance/arrogance.

Comment: @littleadv you're confusing the highly globalized 2000s with the non-so-globalized 1960s, 1970s and 1980s.

Comment: @RonJohn highly globalized 2020 you wanted to say... The OP posted this question last week, not 60 years ago.

Comment: @littleadv but ASCII was created 60 years ago, and .com was created 40 years ago.

Comment: This question was created last week, not 60 years ago. I don't understand the point you're trying to make. Are you saying that it's perfectly fine to assume that a "default" country in the internet is the US? I'm saying that that would be a very arrogant claim, which is unfortunately very typical to people born and raised in thc US. It's like saying that every Catholic must speak Latin. Maybe they did, 2000 years ago, but this is now.

Comment: What is the point of this pointless discussion? It is a forum (site, platform, whatever) which is used worldwide, has country tags for most countries and can be used to ask questions about many jurisdictions. So it doesn't really matter that it is US-based. Besides, a .com domain can be registered worldwide.